# batch rename / re-rename for video encoding

Tags: batch-file, video

i need help to rename some file using bat file. i'm trying to batch encode video with cmd
it goes like this

1. read the name of files and then save it into text file
   (file_read.txt).
2. rename those files into simple name, 1.mp4 2.mp4 etc untill all
   files renamed (xxx.mp4). even if they were wmv/mov/avi, i usually just rename into mp4, dont really know if its bad or not
3. encode the renamed files from 2. this is my code to encode

> .\exe\x264_32_tMod-10bit-all --level 5.1 --preset veryslow --crf 23.0 --min-keyint 12 --scenecut 45 --bframes 8 --b-adapt 2 --ref 10 --weightp 2 --qcomp 0.6 --rc-lookahead 40 --direct auto --aq-mode 3 --aq-strength 0.9 --merange 32 --me umh --subme 10 --trellis 2 --psy-rd 0.40:0.60 --acodec none --stylish --output  .\temp\Output_v.mp4 .\Input\xxx.mp4
>
> .\exe\ffmpeg -y -i .\Input\xxx.mp4 -f wav -| .\exe\neroAacEnc -ignorelength -q 0.4 -if - -of .\temp\Output_a.aac
>
> .\exe\ffmpeg -y -i .\Input\xxx.mp4 -i .\temp\Output_v.mp4 -map 1 -map_metadata 0 -c copy .\temp\newmetadatavideo.mp4
>
> .\exe\ffmpeg -y -i .\temp\newmetadatavideo.mp4 -i .\temp\Output_a.aac -vcodec copy -acodec copy .\Output\yyy.mp4

here the input file is xxx.mp4 and yyy.mp4 is the output

4. re-rename the yyy.mp4 files into file_read.txt. extension will be mp4 (since
   i encode them into mp4)

i'm using subfolder to differentiate input-output-exe file-and stuff, so none of them are actually in one folder. like this

- root (i put bat file here)

  - exe (x264, ffmpeg, nero aac all here)
  - input (where i put all my videos)
  - output (finished videos)
  - temp (i put video-audio and file_read.txt here)

Thank you!

p.s my output file using this code is roughly 2-5 times smaller with small loss (at least for me), but since i use 10 bit and level 5.1, not all player might able to play (havent tried it)

Answer (score 0):

This code should eliminate the need for renaming the files.

Change line 2 so that it shows your correct input filetypes and FWIW the .\ is not necessary in Windows to refer to files or folders in the current directory.

Test it on some sample files first - the command lines are identical to your code, only the input and output terms have been changed.

**EDIT: The last command has ".\Output\%%~na.mp4" instead of ".\Output\%%~nxa"

so it will save all final output files as .mp4**

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("input\*.mpg" "input\*.mkv" "input\*.avi") do (
    .\exe\x264_32_tMod-10bit-all --level 5.1 --preset veryslow --crf 23.0 --min-keyint 12 --scenecut 45 --bframes 8 --b-adapt 2 --ref 10 --weightp 2 --qcomp 0.6 --rc-lookahead 40 --direct auto --aq-mode 3 --aq-strength 0.9 --merange 32 --me umh --subme 10 --trellis 2 --psy-rd 0.40:0.60 --acodec none --stylish --output ".\temp\Output_v_%%~nxa" ".\Input\%%~nxa"
    .\exe\ffmpeg -y -i ".\Input\%%~nxa" -f wav -| .\exe\neroAacEnc -ignorelength -q 0.4 -if - -of ".\temp\Output_a_%%~nxa.aac"
    .\exe\ffmpeg -y -i ".\Input\%%~nxa" -i ".\temp\Output_v_%%~nxa" -map 1 -map_metadata 0 -c copy ".\temp\new_%%~nxa"
    .\exe\ffmpeg -y -i ".\temp\new_%%~nxa" -i ".\temp\Output_a_%%~nxa.aac" -vcodec copy -acodec copy ".\Output\%%~na.mp4"
)
pause
```

Some extra code can be added to delete the temporary files, if it works ok.

Comment: it WORKS!! but i want to have mp4/mkv for all output. how to do it? btw what is %%~nxa means, where can i learn more? thanks

Comment: `%%~nxa` is a reference to the original filename and extension and you can read about the modifiers in the last page of `for /?` help from the cmd prompt.  I edited the code above to save all final output files as `.mp4` extension, but renaming the extension doesn't actually change the media container - although ffmpeg may use it to determine the media container, I'm not sure.  That's just something for you to look into.

Answer (score 0):

i've edit some code

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("input\*.mpg" "input\*.mkv" "input\*.avi" "input\*.mov" "input\*.mp4" "input\*.m4v") do (
.\exe\x264_32_tMod-10bit-all --level 5.1 --preset veryslow --crf 23.0 --min-keyint 12 --scenecut 45 --bframes 8 --b-adapt 2 --ref 10 --weightp 2 --qcomp 0.6 --rc-lookahead 40 --direct auto --aq-mode 3 --aq-strength 0.9 --merange 32 --me umh --subme 10 --trellis 2 --psy-rd 0.40:0.60 --acodec none --stylish --output ".\temp\Output_v.mp4" ".\Input\%%~nxa"
.\exe\ffmpeg -y -i ".\Input\%%~nxa" -f wav -| .\exe\neroAacEnc -ignorelength -q 0.4 -if - -of ".\temp\Output_a.aac"
.\exe\ffmpeg -y -i ".\Input\%%~nxa" -i ".\temp\Output_v.mp4" -map 1 -map_metadata 0 -c copy ".\temp\meta_video.mp4"
.\exe\ffmpeg -y -i ".\temp\meta_video.mp4" -i ".\temp\Output_a.aac" -vcodec copy -acodec copy ".\Output\%%~na.mp4"
)
pause
```

no need to remove temp file, include some other video types and automatically make MP4 file

it's finally DONE, for now!

Thanks for helping me